# Angular How to capture a particular url in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My URL to capture is

http://test.sample.com/?code=4/CAKREYsOD89sg7eXahK93Pw7pnMb5ndkiCrzSUlMS1U

I need to capture the above url in my $routeProvider.
My code is.

```
$routeProvider.when('/:code/',{
                    template: '',
                    controller: function ($location,$rootScope) {
                        console.log("I got you. .. ");
                    }
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/login'
                });
```

My problem is I cant able to capture this url in when.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think its because of "?" try http://test.sample.com/code=4/CAKREYsOD89sg7eXahK93Pw7pnMb5ndkiCrzSUlMS1U

Answer (score 1):

use `$routeParam`

```
$routeProvider.when('/:code/',{
                template: '',
                controller: function ($location,$rootScope) {
                   var urlCopied=$location.path(); // get the current path                     
                }
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
```

hope it helps

Comment: I need to get the above url to be captured. Its not about parsing the url.

Comment: sorry @Explore-X , edited the answer check useful or not.

Comment: Its about $routeProvider.when('/:code/',     The url is not get captured on this wildcard

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

`// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
// => "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"`

Gotten from [Angular js $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do want you need:

1. If you want to capture a special param, don't put it in a query parameter. Use a url like this :

   http://test.sample.com/#/code/CAKREYsOD89sg7eXahK93Pw7pnMb5ndkiCrzSUlMS1U

And catch it like this :

```
$routeProvider.when('/code/codeID',{
                template: '',
                controller: function ($routeParams) {
                    console.log($routeParams.codeID);
                }
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/login'
            });
```

2. If you want use query parameter you can do it like this:

   ```
   $routeProvider.when('/',{
           template: '',
           controller: function ($location) {
              var queryParams = $location.search();
              console.log(queryParams.code);                   
           }
       })
       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/login'
       });
   ```

And use this URL :

```
http://test.sample.com/?code=4/CAKREYsOD89sg7eXahK93Pw7pnMb5ndkiCrzSUlMS1U
```

I hope this code will help you!